# "not a function" when function being used as function parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, npm, data-structures

I am not knowledgeable in NodeJS or JS so bare that in mind. I have been playing around with a radix trie module [Merkle-Patricia-Tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merkle-patricia-tree) and it's taken me down a rabbit hole when using a [level](https://github.com/Level/level) module similar to Google's leveldb to store the radix trie in persistent storage.

**what I think I know**:

1. The [Merkle-Patricia-Tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merkle-patricia-tree) module requires a levelup dependency which wraps level down as the first parameter when instantiating a new trie
2. Seems to write to the store with `trie.put(key,value)`, but having problems reading with `trie.get(key)`
3. In one of the error files in Markle-Patricia-Trie library...

```
constructor(leveldb) {
        this._leveldb = leveldb !== null && leveldb !== void 0 ? leveldb : level();
    }
```

does pass in the `levelup(leveldown('path'))` when instantiating trie with db but somehow says that here in the same file (included affected files)...

```
async get(key) {
        let value = null;
        try {
            value = await this._leveldb.get(key, exports.ENCODING_OPTS);
        }
        catch (error) {
            if (error.notFound) {
                // not found, returning null
            }
            else {
                throw error;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
```

this...

```
(node:17128) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this._leveldb.get is not a function
    at CheckpointDB.get (\cryptoNetwork\node_modules\merkle-patricia-tree\dist\db.js:27:41)
    at CheckpointDB.get (\cryptoNetwork\node_modules\merkle-patricia-tree\dist\checkpointDb.js:85:35)
    at SecureTrie.lookupNode (\cryptoNetwork\node_modules\merkle-patricia-tree\dist\baseTrie.js:250:31)
    at SecureTrie._lookupNode (\cryptoNetwork\node_modules\merkle-patricia-tree\dist\baseTrie.js:266:21)
    at \cryptoNetwork\node_modules\merkle-patricia-tree\dist\util\walkController.js:41:40
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at WalkController.startWalk (\cryptoNetwork\node_modules\merkle-patricia-tree\dist\util\walkController.js:36:22)
    at Function.newWalk (\cryptoNetwork\node_modules\merkle-patricia-tree\dist\util\walkController.js:32:24)
    at SecureTrie.walkTrie (\cryptoNetwork\node_modules\merkle-patricia-tree\dist\baseTrie.js:221:47)
    at \cryptoNetwork\node_modules\merkle-patricia-tree\dist\baseTrie.js:200:28
(node:17128) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, 
or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:17128) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

4. The encoding is dealt with properly so assume under that axiom

**aggregator code**:

```
testing()
    {
        programData.volatile.modularVariables.action = 'read';
        programData.volatile.modularVariables.user = 'blahblahblahblah';
        programData.volatile.modularVariables.createTrie();
    };
```

**object with relevant code** (I'm aware of extra unneeded code, editing time of writing this)

```
//assume object containing these functions/variables inside

user: '-', //aggregator initializes this and action
action: '-',
createTrie: ()=>{switch(programData.volatile.modularVariables.action){case 'read':programData.volatile.modularVariables.read(programData.persistent.paths.srcRoot,programData.volatile.modularVariables.encoding.utf8,programData.volatile.modularVariables.handleTrie);break;case 'write':programData.volatile.modularVariables.read(programData.persistent.paths.srcRoot,programData.volatile.modularVariables.encoding.utf8,programData.volatile.modularVariables.handleTrie);break;case 'new':programData.volatile.modularVariables.newTrie(db);break;default: console.log(`%c${programData.volatile.debug.debugStrings.errCodes.createTrie}: Error with action selection`,'color: red');}},
handleTrie: async (err,data)=>{var userBIN = Buffer.from(programData.volatile.modularVariables.user); var root=Buffer.from(data,programData.volatile.modularVariables.encoding.hex);console.log(root); switch(programData.volatile.modularVariables.action){case 'read': const trie = new merkle_patricia_tree_1.SecureTrie(programData.persistent.paths.srcRoot,root); 
            var result = await trie.get(userBIN); console.log(result)}},
read: (file,encoding,cb)=>{fs.readFile(file,encoding,cb)},
encoding: {utf8:'utf8',hex:'hex',base64:'base64',BIN:(data,encoding)=>{Buffer.from(data,encoding)}}, //Depricate BIN asap,
srcRoot: './vortex/root.txt',
```

**conclusion**
I am stumped, I am not sure what I am doing wrong or what is wrong with [Markle-Patricia-Trie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merkle-patricia-tree) (or the leveldb). My questions are, what am I doing wrong? Can you explain to me what's wrong?. Thank you :).

Comment: So, basic debugging here is to do a `console.log(this._leveldb)` and `console.log(this._leveldb.get)` and see what you have.

Comment: Oh true, I don't know what I'm thinking. So for this._leveldb I got the string of my store path... Interesting so it's returning the path not an instance of class

Comment: I've tried many instances of level, or levelup(leveldown) with the same result so it could possibly be how the two libraries behave with one another. I'm too noob for this though lol

Comment: What is `this._leveldb = leveldb !== null && leveldb !== void 0 ? leveldb : level();` supposed to do?

Comment: WOW I found the issue... I am not passing in the level, just the path....... I am so dumb

Comment: basically, it checks if the level class was passed in, and if not it does an in memory level version of it.

Answer (score 1):

In the handleTrie arrow function I used as callback for the read arrow function, I passed in the path of the store, not the level instance itself...